# TSql Case within Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to do a select statment in tsql with a case within a case. First is based on what the SearchField is. Next I need to do it based on the SearchOper.

```
    declare @searchField varchar(50)  
    declare @searchString varchar(50)
    declare @searchOper varchar(50)

    case @searchField
     when 'CompanyName' then
        case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
            select * from tbl1 where CompanyName = @searchString
         when 'ne' then 
           select * from tbl1 where CompanyName <> @searchString
         end
     when 'StoreNum' then
        case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
             select * from tbl1 where StoreNum = @searchString
          when  'ne' then
             select * from tbl1 where StoreNum <> @searchString
        end 
     end
```

Note what I am trying to do is within the case statement do a select.

I get a message saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example, you probably want to use IF statements (here is an example with ELSE, but you can use IF and ELSE IF multiple times too):

```
declare @searchField varchar(50)  
declare @searchString varchar(50)
declare @searchOper varchar(50)

IF @searchField='CompanyName'
BEGIN
    IF @searchOper='eq'
    BEGIN
        select * from tbl1 where CompanyName = @searchString
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * from tbl1 where CompanyName <> @searchString
    END
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    IF @searchOper='eq'
    BEGIN
        select * from tbl1 where StoreNum = @searchString
    END
    ELSE
        select * from tbl1 where StoreNum <> @searchString
    END
END
```

*CASE is very similar, but is rather used with inline statements (i.e. SELECT CASE 1=1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END).*

Comment: Thanks. Are you certain there is no way to use CASE. I thought about IF as well but though CASE would be more elegant

Comment: When working with the same table across conditions (like in your example) you would really rather want to use something inline (so you hit the table once), optimized and more readable- similar to the example described below by RichardTheKiwi (but watch-out for missing parenthesis). That approach would be more straightforward/standard.

Comment: TO CONTINUE: CASE is really most powerful for working with columns, and making convoluted decisions with order, joins, and where... Sure, CASE could potentially work here as well in a couple of different ways (but, again- quite a bit less readable and a lot less optimized, so would recommend against that):
`select * from tbl1 where (CASE WHEN @searchField='CompanyName' THEN CASE WHEN @searchOper='eq' AND CompanyName = @searchString THEN 1 WHEN @searchOper='ne' AND CompanyName <> @searchString THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END)=1`

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @searchField varchar(50)  
declare @searchString varchar(50)
declare @searchOper varchar(50)

 select *
 from tbl1
 where (@searchField <> 'companyName'
       or
       @searchOper = 'eq' and CompanyName = @searchString
       or
       @searchOper = 'ne' and CompanyName <> @searchString)
   AND (@searchField <> 'StoreNum'
       or
       @searchOper = 'eq' and CompanyName = @searchString
       or
       @searchOper = 'ne' and CompanyName <> @searchString)
 option (recompile)
```

That's one way to write it and it should perform ok.  What you have is a variant of [www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) but `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` should still produce an optimal plan each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @searchField varchar(50)  
declare @searchString varchar(50)
declare @searchOper varchar(50)

SELECT
    (case @searchField
     when 'CompanyName' then
        (case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
            (select * from tbl1 where CompanyName = @searchString)
         when 'ne' then 
           (select * from tbl1 where CompanyName <> @searchString)
         end
         )
     when 'StoreNum' then
        (case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
             (select * from tbl1 where StoreNum = @searchString)
          when  'ne' then
            ( select * from tbl1 where StoreNum <> @searchString)
        end 
        )
     end 
) a
```

im too lazy to build tbl1, change it to getdate instead

```
declare @searchField varchar(50)  
declare @searchString varchar(50)
declare @searchOper varchar(50)

SET @searchField = 'CompanyName'
SET @searchOper = 'eq'
SELECT
    (case @searchField
     when 'CompanyName' then
        (case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
            (select getdate())
         when 'ne' then 
           (select getdate())
         end
         )
     when 'StoreNum' then
        (case @searchOper
          when 'eq' then
             (select getdate())
          when  'ne' then
            ( select getdate())
        end 
        )
     end 
) a
```

Comment: No, the brackets do not help here. CASE just can't be used like this (not in SQL Server). It expects a *scalar expression* after `THEN` (as well as after `ELSE`), not a *query* (or any other kind of *statement*).

Comment: well it worked when I tried it. i am guessing this is what he wants. of course we can suggest a proper way but as the title says. case within case.

Comment: Well, it may have worked if your `tbl1` had just one column and no more than one row. That way `select *` could be considered a scalar expression. Try more than one row and/or more than one column, and that query will fail.

Comment: agreed. missed that. Oh well. I hope he uses IF. their better anyways.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN,

"The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures."

Reference [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)